# How do I increase touchpad sensitivity on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

How do I increase touchpad sensitivity on Ubuntu 21.10? I used to put my signature on some documents by drawing with a stylus on my touchpad(dumb, I know, but stylus feels better than using my finger). After switching to a new HP laptop, the stylus is no longer being detected. It still works on my phone and previous laptop though. I figured increasing the sensitivity might help. Please excuse the dumb questions, I'm still trying to figure things out.